# A class task misbehaved when disable block exists in a task when multiple instances

Tags: system-verilog

I have been debugging a mysterious bug in my systemverilog code for weeks.
My colleague helped me and found that *disable block_name* statement was causing the weird behaviors.

My search yielded the following comment from Dave:
"How to kill a thread from multiple threads launched and wait for all the threads to complete" (Mentor Verification Academy)

> One thing you need to be careful with is if you try to move this code into a class, and there are multiple instances of that class, the disable statement kills all threads named Th3.

This explains why my systemverilog code misbehaved.

But I now don't know why systemverilog standard specifies that way.
Is there any reason why the standard was defined that way?
As task in a class is implicitly declared as automatic, I *assumed* each instances are completely independent.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This behavior comes from Verilog, and must remain this way for backward compatibility. The `disable` statement can be used from outside the scope of what is being disabled, and there is no syntax to specify a specific instance of a scope.

The situation is related to declaring a static variable inside a named block or task. The scope name you use to access that static variable is *static* as well

Comment: Thank you, Dave, for answering my question. Systemverilog inherited goods and bads (limitations) from the original Verilog. I now understand why Systemverilog introduced "continue" and "break".